# ERROR ITMS-90207: Bundle does not contain a bundle executable

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, xcode8

I'm trying to upload my iOS app to the App Store, but getting the error:
ERROR ITMS-90207: Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'xxx.app' does not contain a bundle executable."
This is the first time after updating the project to XCode 8 and Swift 3 I'm trying to submit the app. With previous versions of XCode I didn't see this problem.
I've checked stack overflow for any clues but all answers didn't help.
My project has ObjC and swift code. It uses CocoaPods 1.1.1
In the info.plist I have:

```
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
```

I'm fighting with this for 2 days already trying to play with settings, but no luck so far.

Comment: If you look within that `xxx.app` folder, do you see a file named `xxx` (i.e. the same name as the bundle).  That would be the executable. If you don't see the executable file, what's the largest single file (and not a folder) that lives in the `xxx.app` bundle folder?

Comment: I see the xxx inside the xxx.app. So, I do have executable in my bundle.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. Struggled for 2 days

I solved the problem by **Changing The File Name**. i changed mine from xxx.ipa to xxx_b.ipa.

I think application loader has a cache feature somewhere. 
For my case, the first round i uploaded a bad ipa. 
Then i corrected it and repeat the process and it keep giving me the same 90207 error.
Tried every solution from [updating iTMS Transporter](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/76803) to recreating all certificates. In the end, changing the filename solved it.

I use Application Loader standalone version.
Hope this helps someone